# Convert Pandas DataFrame Column From String to Int Based on Conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

df

```
viz  a1_count  a1_mean     a1_std
n         3        2   0.816497
y         0      NaN        NaN 
n         2       51  50.000000
```

I want to convert the "viz" column to 0 and 1, based on a conditional. I've tried:

```
df['viz'] = 0 if df['viz'] == "n" else 1
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're trying to compare a scalar with the entire series which raise the `ValueError` you saw. A simple method would be to cast the boolean series to `int`:

```
In [84]:
df['viz'] = (df['viz'] !='n').astype(int)
df

Out[84]:
   viz  a1_count  a1_mean     a1_std
0    0         3        2   0.816497
1    1         0      NaN        NaN
2    0         2       51  50.000000
```

You can also use `np.where`:

```
In [86]:
df['viz'] = np.where(df['viz'] == 'n', 0, 1)
df

Out[86]:
   viz  a1_count  a1_mean     a1_std
0    0         3        2   0.816497
1    1         0      NaN        NaN
2    0         2       51  50.000000
```

Output from the boolean comparison:

```
In [89]:
df['viz'] !='n'

Out[89]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: viz, dtype: bool
```

And then casting to `int`:

```
In [90]:
(df['viz'] !='n').astype(int)

Out[90]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
Name: viz, dtype: int32
```

Comment: stumbled upon this post while researching something. 2 years later, there may be new options now.  In my code just used this: `pd.to_numeric(myDF['myDFCell'], errors='coerce')`.  This is probably newer pandas syntax.  The coerce flag tells it to convert that which cannot be converted to number to NA so it won't throw errors.

Comment: @TMWP that maybe true but the OP doesn't want to convert 'n' to a numeric which would convert in this case to `NaN` so this is slightly different use case here

Comment: Right.  Just a useful addition.  I came to this post while researching how to convert a string column in Pandas to numeric.  This was the closest hit to that question that stack overflow came up with.

Answer (score 4):

From @TMWP's comment above:

`pd.to_numeric(myDF['myDFCell'], errors='coerce')`

It works like a charm and is a quick and simple one liner