# Apply for loop in multiple dataframe for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Dataframe is like below: Where I want to change dataframes value to 'dead' if age is more than 100.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,210],'age2': [10,20,150],'name': ['a','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','name'])

raw_data = {'age1': [80,90,110],'age2': [70,120,90],'name': ['a','b','c']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','name'])
```

Desired outcome

```
df=
    age1    age2    name
0   23      10       a
1   45      20       b
2   dead    dead     c

df2=
    age1    age2    name
0   80      70       a
1   90      dead     b
2   dead    90       c
```

I was trying something like this:

```
col_list=['age1','age2']
df_list=[df,df2]

def dead(df):
  for df in df_list:
    if df.columns in col_list:
      if df.columns >=100:
        return 'dead'
    else:
      return df.columns

df.apply(dead)
```

Error shown:
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I am looking for a loop that works on all dataframe.

Please correct my function also for future learning :)

Comment: the error is saying you are trying to use logic on an array instead of a value which it cannot do. For example if value == 0; this is good for value as long as it isn't an array of values.

Comment: also you have def dead(df) but also use df in df_list. You therefore have df twice. This is messy and not advised. It could cause issues. Change one of those and its associated variables.

Comment: Also, instead of iterating through pandas dataframes use the where clause. Iterating through pandas scales horribly. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-where/

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for a for loop, as I can't apply the fun on a list of dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#inspired by @jib and @ravinder

```
col_list=['age1','age2']
df_list=[df,df2]

for d in df_list:
  for c in col_list:
    d[c]=np.where(d[c]>100,'dead',d[c])
df #or df2
```

output:

```
   age1  age2 name
0    23    10    a
1    45    20    b
2  dead  dead    c
```

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) functions of pandas, numpy respectively.

```
c = df.filter(regex='age\d+').columns
df[c] = np.where(df[c].ge(100),'dead',df[c])
df
```

---

---

Alternative approach with `where`:

```
c=df.filter(like='age').columns
df[c] = df[c].where(~df['c'].ge(100),'dead')
```

***Explanation:***

- Getting columns which has same name like `age` in c variable.
- Then using `np.where` to check if respective(all age columns) are greeter/equal to 100, if yes then set it to dead or keep it as it is.

Comment: you can just do a where on the df itself which is faster right?

Comment: @JustinOberle, `np.where` and `where` works equally(logic wise). Sometimes `np.where` is even faster too.

Comment: @JustinOberle, I have also added answer with `where` here too, along with documentation link and explanation, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following:

```
col_list=['age1','age2']
df_list=[df,df2]

for d in df_list:
    for c in col_list:
        d.loc[d[c]>100, c] = 'dead'
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use Pandas' `mask`, which is similar to `if-else`, but vectorized.

```
def dead(df):
    col_list = ['age1', 'age2']
    df = df.copy()
    temporary = df.filter(col_list)
    temporary = temporary.mask(temporary >= 100, "dead")
    df.loc[:, col_list] = temporary
    return df
```

Apply function to the dataframe:

```
df.pipe(dead)
 
   age1  age2 name
0    23    10    a
1    45    20    b
2  dead  dead    c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def check_more_than_100(x):
    v = None
    try:
        v = int(x)
    except:
        pass
    if v is not None:
        return (v > 100)
    return (False)
    
df['age1'] = df['age1'].apply(lambda x : 'dead' if check_more_than_100(x) else x)
df['age2'] = df['age2'].apply(lambda x : 'dead' if check_more_than_100(x) else x)

df2['age1'] = df2['age1'].apply(lambda x : 'dead' if check_more_than_100(x) else x)
df2['age2'] = df2['age2'].apply(lambda x : 'dead' if check_more_than_100(x) else x)
```

This should take care of non-int values if any.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790334/9737325) to a similar question. Basically you can use the .where() function from numpy to set based on the conditional.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,210],'age2': [10,20,150],'name': ['a','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','name'])

raw_data = {'age1': [80,90,110],'age2': [70,120,90],'name': ['a','b','c']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','name'])

col_list=['age1','age2']
df_list=[df,df2]

def dead(df_list, col_list):
    for df in df_list:
        for col in col_list:
            df[col] = np.where(df[col] >= 100, "dead", df[col])
    return df_list


df

dead([df], col_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting numeric columns and then using numpy where -

```
df_cols  = df._get_numeric_data().columns.values
df2_cols  = df2._get_numeric_data().columns.values
df[df_cols] = np.where(df[df_cols].to_numpy() > 100, 'dead', df[df_cols])
df2[df2_cols] = np.where(df2[df2_cols].to_numpy() > 100, 'dead', df2[df2_cols])
```